# For Loop Question. let n = 0; let x = 0; while (n < 3) { n++; x += n; } Why does the X value change?

Tags: for-loop

Why is it that X value changes. I understand why n value changes, but why does X Value change?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD1hY.png)

Comment: You'll need to mention (and tag) what programming language you're talking about. And please add the code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Why shouldn't it change? Is your question perhaps just what `+=` does?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use the `+=` operator.
It's the same as `x = x + n;`

Comment: I understand the += operator.    let n = 0;
let x = 0;
while (n < 3) {
  n++;
  x += n;
}                      What I can't wrap my head around is, how does x when starting at 0 gets to gets to 6?

Comment: We start with x=0 and n=0. We enter the while loop. Is n <3? Yes->n=1;x+=n==>(n=1;x=1). Is n <3? Yes->n=2;x+=n==>(n=2;x=3). Is n < 3? Yes -> n=2; x+=n ==>(n=3;x=6). Is n<3? No, leave the loop